# Sort dataGridView Column by Fore Text Color

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview with data, the data rows are colored (Only Text Coloring) as following: Red, Orange & Black
for example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Value.ToString())
            {
                case "SDP":
                    e.Value = "Schedule Departure";
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "CKN":
                    e.Value = "Check-In";
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
                    break;
                case "P2G":
                    e.Value = "Proceed to Gate";
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
}
```

I also create Groupbox with few Radio Buttons to change soring

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListSortDirection direction;
        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        dataGridView1.Sort(arrTimeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,direction);
    }
```

But the question is: how can I change sorting depending on the color of the text, for example: RED, ORANGE then Black ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column in your `datagridview` where you can keep a number of `ForeColor`. 
For example :

column will be named as `dataGridView_ForeColorNum`, and values will be as next:

```
RED = 1
ORANGE = 2
BLACK = 3
```

then in handler `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` set this value same time with changing a `ForeColor` of the row

```
cswitch (e.Value.ToString())
{
    case "SDP":
        e.Value = "Schedule Departure";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView_ForeColorNum.Name].Value = 1;     
        break;
    case "SKN":
        e.Value = "Check-In";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView_ForeColorNum.Name].Value = 2;
        break;
    case "P2G":
        e.Value = "Proceed to gate";
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView_ForeColorNum.Name].Value = 3;            break;


}
```

Sorting will be as normal, but use for sorting a new column with number given to ForeColor:

```
 private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ListSortDirection direction;
     direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
     dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView_ForeColorNum,direction);
 }
```

For Data-bound DataGridView previous solution will not work because predefined column's property `IsDataBound` = False. [MSDN:datagridview.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0868ft3z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**In this case first workaround solution which came in my mind was:**

In your SQL query add one more column where you will set `ForeColor` number using `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
CASE yourValueColumn
WHEN 'SDP' THEN 1
WHEN 'SKN' THEN 2
WHEN 'P2G' THEN 3
ELSE 0 END AS ForeColor
```

In datagridview's predefined column `dataGridView_ForeColorNum` set property `DataProperty = "ForeColor"` and `datagridview_CellFormatting` handler will be as next:

```
{
    if(this.datagridview1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != this.dataGridView_ForeColorNum.Name)
        return;
    //if column is ForeColumn then set a ForeColor independent on the column value
    switch ((int)e.Value)
    {
        case 1: //SDP
            e.Value = "Schedule Departure";
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;     
            break;
        case 2: //SKN
            e.Value = "Check-In";
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            break;
        case 3: //P2G
            e.Value = "Proceed to gate";
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's an amazing idea, but it gives me the following error: Data-bound DataGridView control can only be sorted on data-bound columns.
Parameter name: dataGridViewColumn

Comment: @NawafAl-Mishri, I updated my answer. Idea is just create a column of ForeColor on database level and then bound to DataGridView where you van then set ForeColor and sort it

Comment: thank a lot for this solution, yes i did something approximately smiler to this and it works fine now :) thanks a lot for your hint you were so helpful brother